# How to group Table Header - SAPUI5 xml

Tags: sapui5

I need to have multiple header in a table using SAPUI5 XML.

This is what I have tried. **[JsBin](https://jsbin.com/lurewes/edit?html,js,output)**

```
<table:Table title="Real-time order status" noDataText="No data to display" id="tableDisp" enableBusyIndicator="true" showNoData="true" width="auto" class="sapUiResponsiveMargin">
                                    <table:Column id="col6" hAlign="Center" headerSpan="[2,1]">
                    <table:multiLabels>
                        <Label text="2 - Batch records handed over to QA"    class="tableHeaderWrap"/>
                        <Label text="Target" textAlign="Center"  />
                    </table:multiLabels>
                    <table:template>
                        <Label text="{Target}"/>
                    </table:template>
                </table:Column>
                <table:Column id="col10" hAlign="Center">
                    <table:multiLabels>
                        <Label text="2 - Batch records handed over to QA"    class="tableHeaderWrap"/>
                        <Label text="Actual" textAlign="Center"/>
                    </table:multiLabels>
                    <table:template>
                        <Label text="{Actual}"/>
                    </table:template>
                </table:Column>
```

What I need is : -
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What ever you have tried is fine. But while adding the header span instead of the array just give 2 as below you can see this [thread](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3916477).

This answer is for the data present in the jsbin.

```
<Page title="{i18n>title}">
    <content>
        <table:Table title="Real-time order status" noDataText="No data to display" id="tableDisp" enableBusyIndicator="true" showNoData="true" width="auto" class="sapUiResponsiveMargin">
            <table:Column id="col6" headerSpan="2" colspan="2">
                <table:multiLabels >
                    <Label text="Batch records" textAlign="Center" width="100%"/>
                    <Label text="Target" textAlign="Center" width="100%"/>
                </table:multiLabels>
                <table:template>
                    <Text text="Target"/>
                </table:template>
            </table:Column>
            <table:Column id="col10">
                <table:multiLabels>
                    <Label text="Batch records" textAlign="Center"/>
                    <Label text="Actual" textAlign="Center" width="100%"/>
                </table:multiLabels>
                <table:template>
                    <Text text="Actual"/>
                </table:template>
             </table:Column>
         </table:Table>
     </content>
</Page>
```

Or you have to get the column by id in the controller and then you have to set the headerspan.

For your above code add the **width**, "textAlign" and change the **headerSpan** property as below

```
<table:Table title="Real-time order status" noDataText="No data to display" id="tableDisp" enableBusyIndicator="true" showNoData="true" width="auto" class="sapUiResponsiveMargin">
  <table:Column id="col6" hAlign="Center" headerSpan="2">
    <table:multiLabels>
        <Label text="2 - Batch records handed over to QA" textAlign="Center" width="100%" class="tableHeaderWrap"/>
        <Label text="Target" textAlign="Center" width="100%" />
    </table:multiLabels>
    <table:template>
        <Label text="{Target}"/>
    </table:template>
  </table:Column>
  <table:Column id="col10" hAlign="Center">
    <table:multiLabels>
        <Label text="2 - Batch records handed over to QA" textAlign="Center" width="100%" class="tableHeaderWrap"/>
        <Label text="Actual" textAlign="Center" width="100%"/>
    </table:multiLabels>
    <table:template>
        <Label text="{Actual}"/>    
    </table:template>
  </table:Column>
</table:Table>
```